# How to create admin panel in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function init_form_fields() {
    $this->form_fields = array(
        'enabled' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce_payu_in' ),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __( 'Enable PayUMoney', 'woocommerce_payu_in' ),
            'default' => 'yes'
            )
    );
}
```

I am getting this code from pay-u plugin. Using this code I want to create my own admin panel, but I don't understand what this code means.

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial page of wordpress where you can find a solution to add a admin page.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Wordpress Information:

> Here is a very simple example of the three steps just described. This
>   plugin will add a sub-level menu item under the Settings top-level
>   menu, and when selected, that menu item will cause a very basic screen
>   to display. Note: this code should be added to a main plugin PHP file
>   or a separate PHP include file.

This is the wordpress example code:

```
<?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I have done with menu page but i wants to create form fields in that page . i have no idea how to make it.?